# How to convert a plain object into an ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For some reason I can't find this simple thing in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (maybe I'm just missing it).

I expected this to work:

```
const map = new Map({foo: 'bar'});

map.get('foo'); // 'bar'
```

...but the first line throws `TypeError: (var)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`

How do I make a Map from a plain object? Do I really have to first convert it into an array of arrays of key-value pairs?

Comment: FWIW, it may be worth switching your accepted answer from [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644532/157247) to [nils'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644558/157247) or [bergi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644965/157247). `Object.entries` really is the better approach over `Object.keys`, and bergi's generator function approach is slightly more direct than either `Object.keys` or `Object.entries`.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

Yes, the `Map` constructor takes an array of key-value pairs.

`Object.entries` is a new Object static method available in [ES2017 (19.1.2.5)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries({foo: 'bar'}));

map.get('foo'); // 'bar'
```

[It's currently implemented in Firefox 46+ and Edge 14+ and newer versions of Chrome](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-Object.entries)

If you need to support older environments and transpilation is not an option for you, use a polyfill, such as the one recommended by georg:

```
Object.entries = typeof Object.entries === 'function' ? Object.entries : obj => Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]]);
```

Comment: A "polyfill" will be rather trivial: `Object.entries = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]])`

Comment: Re your comment at the end, I figure if they're using `const`, they're transpiling. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's probably true :) not sure if they're only transpiling ES2015 though.

Comment: `Object.entries` landed in Node 7.x proper (without a flag) btw

Comment: Not only is Object.entries in Node7, it is also part of the ES2017 final specification. Thus, this should be the accepted answer, IMO

Comment: @AnilRedshift - Well, this or [the generator function answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644965/157247), since the OP asked for a solution avoiding intermediaries.

Comment: Will this preserve or enforce any key ordering?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not.

Comment: IE doesn't support it :-(

Answer (score 39):

> Do I really have to first convert it into an array of arrays of key-value pairs?

No, an iterator of key-value pair arrays is enough. You can use the following to avoid creating the intermediate array:

```
function* entries(obj) {
    for (let key in obj)
        yield [key, obj[key]];
}

const map = new Map(entries({foo: 'bar'}));
map.get('foo'); // 'bar'
```

Comment: Nice example - just a note to others, you might want to do a `if(!obj.hasOwnProperties(key)) continue;` right after the for loop condition to ensure that you do not yield properties inherited from the object prototype (unless you trust the object, but should do this anyways when iterating objects using `in` as a good habit).

Comment: @Puiu No, you should not, and it's a bad habit. If you don't trust the object, you must not trust its `.hasOwnProperty` property as well, and you'd have to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)`

Comment: @Bergi that's a good point, it could be the case that the object's`hasOwnProperty` has also been overwritten. Are you saying it's good practice then to not bother with checking? Just curious, all the conventions out there say to check or they suggest to avoid using for...in anyways. I'd like to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: Yes, I think not bothering is the best practice. You should trust all the objects that are worth enumerating (i.e. key-value-maps) to not have any enumerable inherited properties. (And yes of course [avoid enumerating arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)). If you have a rare case of enumerating something else, and you bother, you should at least do it properly with `call`. All the conventions out there that recommend `obj.hasOwnProperties(key)` appear to have no idea what they are doing.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the response, trust but verify (if needed :P) and don't abuse for-in by using it on non-objects

Comment: Converting an `Object` into a `Map` is an expensive operation and the OP specifically asked for a solution without intermediates. So why isn't this the excepted answer? Well, asking this is probably futile, it just annoys me.

Comment: In TypeScript, this prompts an error of `Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [any, any]>): Map<any, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Generator<any[], void, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [any, any]>'.` Any idea of this means?

Comment: @tmvnty You might need to spell out the type `function* entries<T>(obj: T): Generator<readonly [keyof T, T[keyof T]]> {…}`. Also `yield [key, obj[key]] as const;` would help TypeScript realise that it's yielding tuples, not arrays.

Comment: The function signature specified in @Bergi's comment has an `any` return type for the generator. To avoid this, you'll want to specify `Generator<readonly [keyof T, T[keyof T]], void>` as the return value (adding `, void`).

Answer (score 29):

[The answer by Nils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644558/5218951) describes *how* to convert objects to maps, which I found very useful. However, the OP was also wondering where this information is in the MDN docs. While it may not have been there when the question was originally asked, it is now on the MDN page for [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Converting_an_Object_to_a_Map) under the heading [Converting an Object to a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Converting_an_Object_to_a_Map) which states:

> **Converting an Object to a Map**
>
> The `new Map()` constructor accepts an iterable of `entries`. With `Object.entries`, you can easily convert from `Object` to `Map`:
>
> ```
> const obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 }; 
> const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));
> console.log(map); // Map { foo: "bar", baz: 42 }
> ```

Answer (score 17):

ES6

convert object to map:

```
const objToMap = (o) => new Map(Object.entries(o));
```

convert map to object:

```
const mapToObj = (m) => [...m].reduce( (o,v)=>{ o[v[0]] = v[1]; return o; },{} )
```

Note: the mapToObj function assumes map keys are strings (will fail otherwise)

Comment: You can do the following to convert the map back to an object: `Object.fromEntries(map.entries())`

Answer (score 10):

```
const myMap = new Map(
    Object
        .keys(myObj)
        .map(
            key => [key, myObj[key]]
        )
)
```

Comment: Fusion of @Ohar's and @TJCrowder's solutions: `var buildMap2 = o => new Map(Object.keys(o).map(k => [k, o[k]]));`.

Comment: Thanks, as I needed to sort the object keys too!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use the [lodash toPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs) method:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const map = new Map(_.toPairs({foo: 'bar'}));
```