# Angular 2 TypeScript using es6 Map type in Response DTO type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can I use es6 Map type in a HTTP Response DTO?

For instance Angular 2 request:

```
 public loadFoos(): Observable<FoosWrapper> {
    return this.http.get("/api/foo")
        .map(res => res.json());

}
```

And a DTO

```
export class FoosWrapper{

    foos: Map<string, Foo[]>;

}
```

After res.json() I am receiving simple object instead of Map.

I know I have to convert data myself into the Map, but what is the best approach for this? 
Iterating over the properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Map in Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what is the best approach for this?

I would just make it a map manually same as you would in JavaScript:

```
const buildMap = o => Object.keys(o).reduce((m, k) => m.set(k, o[k]), new Map());
```

Function borrowed from [How to convert a plain object into an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map)