# Typescript can not read a map<string,string> from JSON data

Tags: json, spring, typescript, angular5

I am using Angular5 on a spring boot application. I am trying to return a Map in JSON.

Spring :

```
//some method
return ResponseEntity.ok((new Gson()).toJson(/*My map object*/));
```

Angular5 :

```
sql_list = new Map<string,string>();
this.myService.getQueries().subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log("Received data: ");
        console.log(data);
        this.sql_list = data;
        console.log(this.sql_list.get("query1"));
    } 
);
```

In the client I can see that the data is well received using console.log :

```
Received data:
{
  "query1" : "select * from test",
  "query2" : "select * from test2",
  "query3" : "select * from test3"
}
```

But `sql_list` object gives me that error when trying to use `map.get(string key)` method  :

**ERROR TypeError: _this.sql_list.get is not a function**

Which mistake did I do there?

**EDIT:** following Florian answer this is working:

```
this.sql_list = new Map<string, string>(Object.entries(data));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first line, you create a Map:

```
sql_list = new Map<string,string>();
```

But later on, in the data handler, you just overwrite that object with the received data:

```
this.sql_list = data;
```

As `data` is something returned by the HTTP handler, it will most likely not fulfill the `Map` interface and not offer functions like `get`. Instead, it will be a plain JavaScript object which you could read like `console.log(sql_list['query1'])`.

You could use some clever combination of `Object.keys()` and `set()` (of your empty `Map` object stored in `sql_list`) to "convert" the returned JavaScript object `data` into a full `Map` object.

Answer (score 4):

As Florian explained, you are assigning plane JSON object to something that should be `Map`
One thing that you can do if you really want it to be `Map` is to do

```
for (const key in data) {
    this.sql_list.set(key, data[key]);
}
```

This will loop through all keys you have ('query1', 'query2', 'query3') and then it will set value of that key in your map

Just wondering why are you using `Map`, because if you already know how your object will look like, and which fields it will have, why don't you just make a class and type it as that class?

Just a suggestion. Also easier when you write code in VS Code for example, you will have autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

When you do `this.sql_list = data`, you overwrite whatever `sql_list` was before, so it's no longer a `Map<string, string>`. Because `data` is a plain javascript object, that's what `sql_list` will be as well.

There aren't many cases where you need to use `Map<string, string>` instead of plain objects, because you can access object values by indexing like this: `sql_list['query1']`. to make this possible in typescript, you have to declare `sql_list` as an `any` type, or create your own type, for example a string mapper type like this:

```
interface strMap {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

then you just declare `sql_list: strMap;`.

If you still have a good reason to use `Map<string, string>`, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map)