# An Easy Way to Convert Object to List of Name Value Pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to convert an object to name value pairs like jquery generates with `.serializeArray()`

This doesn't work:

```
var data = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
    isMale: true,
    occupation: null
}

var serialized = $(data).serailizeArray();
```

Is there an easy way to do this without looking at every property and converting them to name-value pairs?

I'm using a helper function that is written by someone else that adds a name value pair to each call before posting it to the server. Obviously it's not working if I give it a regular object or an array that has a regular object.

Comment: JS has no concept of a 'list of name/value pairs' other than an object, so could you please give an exact example of the output you're attempting to create

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `[{name: value},{age: value},{isMale: value},{occupation: value}]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map

Comment: @KevinB that's what I assumed, but you know what they say about assumptions :)

Comment: Don't have to assume, `like jquery generates with .serializeArray()` it's right there in the question

Comment: That's not what `serializeArray()` does then. That would give you: `[{ name: "name", value: "John" }, ...]`. Hence my point about needing clarification

Comment: In my experience, any time you end up with an array of single key/pair values, you've probably designed the wrong data structure...

Comment: @Alnitak but serializeArray() doesn't do that...it's keys are always `name` and `value`

Comment: @Alnitak Mapping over an array of key, value pairs is less work than mapping over an array of object keys and accessing each property explicitly.

Comment: @Tex only if you're using `key: keyValue, value: actualValue` type objects - if the `key` has a different name in each of the objects you still have to enumerate the object to find that key.

Comment: @Alnitak I'm talking about an array of `[key, value]` pairs such as that generated by `Object.entries()`, to be clear.

Comment: @Tex to be clear, I was talking about arrays like `[ {key1: value1}, {key2: value2}, ...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `Object.entries` and `map` (assuming you want the data in the same format that [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns):

```js
var data = {
  name: "John",
  age: 26,
  isMale: true,
  occupation: null
};

var result = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => ({name: k, value: v}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick if you're using ES6:

```js
var data = {
    name: "John",
    age: 26,
    isMale: true,
    occupation: null
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(data).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }))
)

// ES5:

console.log(
  Object.keys(data).map(function (name) { return { name: name, value: data[name] } })
)
```

Comment: That is not same structure that serializeArray produces

Comment: @charlietfl looks like an exact match to me.

Comment: @charlietfl Indeed. 'name, value pairs' reminded me of 'key, value pairs', which is what `Object.entries()` returns without processing. I glossed over the `serializeArray` part of the question and was unfamiliar with that method until looking it up just now.