# Convert a FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot into a list/map in Node.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, list, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can one convert a  FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot to a list/map for parsing thought it afterwards?

The number of the fields varies in each document so it can't be done manually.

Nothing useful in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot):

```
exports.userDetailsForm = functions.firestore.
document('responseClientDetails/{details}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const newValue = snap.data();
  const caseReference = snap.id;



  return Promise
});
```

Comment: `newValue` is just a plain old JavaScript object, so you can use whatever techniques you would normally use to iterate an object's properties and values.  There is nothing special required by Cloud Firestore - it's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) you refer to, a `DocumentSnapshot` will return "an Object containing all fields in the document".

If you want to transform this Object into a map, you may use some of the techniques described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map). For example:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
          console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        }
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```