# Angular, JSON map data isn´t transformed into a map

Tags: java, json, angular

A project entity has the following field(java):

```
Map<String, String> employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I serialize the project with JSON and send it to my Angular frontend. The Map gets transformed into this form:

```
"employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap":{ 
   "someEmail123123@email.com":"23",
   "someEmail123132423@email.com":"123",
   "someEmail1232341123@email.com":"12",
   "someEmail123123123@email.com":"23"
}
```

In Angular, i defined the field of the object im trying to receive the following way:

```
employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap?: Map<string, string>;
```

When i do a GET-request to receive all projects

```
  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(BASE_URL, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      )
  }
```

the `empoyeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap` data isn´t transformed to a map. I receive the data without errors, but none of the map operators work.

For example, if i did

```
getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(BASE_URL, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        tap(projects => projects.forEach(project => {
          console.log(project.employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap);
          console.log(project.employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap.size);
        })),
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      )
  }
```

it would log all the data saved in `project.employeeToLoggedTimeMap`, but `project.employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap.size` would return undefined and all other map operators don´t work too. So it seems like it does not recognize and transform the data into the map. So, how would i transform the data i get into the map i want?

Comment: You try to use Java method in Angular, of course it's not working

Comment: What do you mean? `size` is a normal javascript/typescript method

Comment: try: const mapped = new Map(projects); mapped.forEach....

Comment: Ouh, i have the map defined inside `export class Project { // here }` which is defined in a different file. Thats not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map) may be what you are looking for. Typescript doesn't convert things for you, it trusts when you specify types even if the thing you receive from server is not what it expects it will pretend that it is.

Answer (score 1):

that is because when you get it from the server it will be as a JSON object so your HashMap will actually be something like a class/interface;
What you need to do is convert the object to a Map, to do this i suggest you create a constructor for **Project** like so:

```js
export class Porject {
  employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap: Map<string, int>;
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
  ..other properties
  
  constructor(item: any) {
    this.employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap = new Map(Object.entries(item.employeeEmailToLoggedTimeMap));
    this.property1 = item.property1;
    this.property2 = item.property2;
  }
}
```

then you can simply:

```js
 return this.http.get<Project[]>(BASE_URL, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        map(projects => projects.map(x => new Project(x)),
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      )
```