# Creating a map in typescript

Tags: typescript

I create a map in typescript like this:

```
let typeMap = new Map();
```

And set a key: string value like this:

```
typeMap.set("key", "value");
```

I can successfully get value by doing this:

```
typeMap.get("key")
```

However, I want set multiple key value pairs to the map and setting each key value would be too much code. I tried doing this:

```
let typeMap = new Map<string, string>();
typeMap = {
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2"
   //etc
}
```

But I'm getting

> Object literal may only specify known properties and "key1" does not exist in type 'Map

I also tried the following:

```
  type typeMap = {
    [key: string]: string
  }
  let typeMap = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
```

If I try to get a static value like this:

```
typeMap["key1"]
```

It works. However, I have a variable that must be passed as key to get the value and when I try to do this:

```
typeMap[variable]
```

I'm getting:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "key1": string; "key2": string; "key3": string; }'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "key1": string; "key2": string; "key3": string; }'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a plain object into an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be confused with `Map` and JavaScript `objects`. A simple javascript object such as `{}` is not the same thing as `new Map()`. You've defined the `typeMap` as a "map", and then you are trying to update it with an object. Either use `Map` and then use `.get/.set` or use an `object` with your the interface you want:

```js
// Use type
const typeMap = new Map<string, string>();
typeMap.set('key1', 'value1');

// would print value1
console.log(typeMap.get('key1'));


// Or use an interface
interface IMap {
    [key: string]: string;
}
const objectMap: IMap = {};
objectMap.key1 = 'value1';

const key = 'key1';
// in both cases, prints value1
console.log(objectMap.key1);
console.log(objectMap(key));
```