# How to convert DocumentSnapshot.data() object to Map in Typescript with Firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am currently doing some Angular Ionic project with Firestore and stuck with one problem. Take following code as an example:

```js
handler: data => {
     firebase.firestore().collection("categories").doc(`${data.name}`).get()
     .then((ds) => {
     if (!ds.exists){
         console.log("No such category");
     }
     else{ 
         let data = ds.data();
         let interested : Map<string, boolean> = data["interested"];
         console.log(Array.from(interested.keys());
         console.log(interested);
     }
});
```

In my database I have following field:
[image: data]

Upon running the code, I get following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: interested.keys is not a function. (In 'interested.keys()', 'interested.keys' is undefined)

When I checked the type of "interested", it returned object while I expected it to be Map. Actually, none of the Map methods work on that variable. I want to use such methods, however, I do not know how to make them work. Why it does not work and what should I do? May be I have to convert data Firestore returns into JSON object?

Comment: There's nothing different about an object returned from data() than any other plain JavaScript object.  And TypeScript's Map is the same as ES6 map, except it adds generics.  Hence, the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't ever worked with Maps, after seeing [nils's answer on "How to convert a plain object into an ES6 Map"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644558/6002078),
I believe you can do this:

```
const safeObject = data['interested'] || {}; // because it might be undefined
let interested: Map<string, boolean> = new Map(Object.entries(safeObject));
```