# Convert a result of type Object into a Map<string, string[]> in Angular

Tags: angular

I am getting a data of type ANY from the backend c# in angular .

It is coming in the form of object .

I want to convert this object into a type of **Map<string, string[]>();** in Angular , so that i get VA as the key , and the 3 strings as the value .

Can anyone help me with this please ?

Comment: add your current code

Comment: Have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a wroker function you can use:

```
function buildMap(obj: any) {
    let map = new Map();
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {       
        map.set(key, obj[key]);
    });
    return map;
}
```

For more options please see answers in this SO: [How to convert a plain object into an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object, regardless of type, that is:

```
const obj: any = {
  $id: "1",
  VA305: ["0000034", "8008200", "0000000"],
}
```

All that's required to convert that into a map is just:

```
const yourMap: Map<string, string[]> = new Map();
const key = 'VA305';

map.set(key, obj[key]);
```

If you need to set a map value for each key in the object, or only certain keys in a loop, you can do that too:

```
const keys: string[] = Object.keys(obj);
const yourMap: Map<string, string[]> = new Map();

keys.forEach(key => {
  if (key !== '$id') {
    map.set(key, obj[key])
  }
});
```

Comment: Here you took const key = 'VA305' , hardcoding it . Any way to pull it from the object ?

Comment: Thank you . Much appreciated