# Map attribute of my class isn't recognised as a Map in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this class:

```
export class Example {

  id: number;
  name: string;
  map: Map<string,boolean>;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, map: Map<string,boolean>) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.map = map;
  }

}
```

And when I try to call the `get()` on the map attribute of an instance like this:

`let temp = example.map.get("key");`

I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: example.map.get is not a function

Also I'm using Spring boot so how can I make sure I'm sending and receiving the map attribute without messing it up?

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it recognized as a Map?

And this returns `false`:

`map instanceof Map`

And the empty attribute looks like this when I show it on the website:
`\[object Object\]`

**Edit:**
I create instances in 2 ways:

1. When the data arrives from the backend:

in the service.ts file:

```
getExamples(): Observable<Example[]>{
   return this.http.get<Example[]>(this.baseUrl);
}
```

in the component.ts file:

```
this.exampleService.getExamples().subscribe((data: Example[]) => {
   console.log('Received examples: ',data);
   this.examples = data;
});
```

I logged it and the Map attribute looks like this in the data:

`Object { "text": true }`

2. When the user creates a new instance with a Form:

```
    const example= this.exampleForm.value as Example;
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you initialize a new Example object. Your class definition looks fine, so you are probably not constructing the Map parameter correctly.

Comment: Agreed, please show us the code where you construct an instance of the `Example` class, surely the problem lies there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a plain object into an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644438/how-to-convert-a-plain-object-into-an-es6-map)